# Git Checkout ignore directory

Tags: git

So if possible i would like to do a git checkout but ignore one folder

Here is my post-receive command

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE="../" git checkout -f
```

I would like to checkout everything aside from the folder wp-content/uploads

On checkout can you ignore directories?

USE CASE: As people upload new files to the uploads folder, if i make a code change and push with GIT i do not want the new files in the uploads folder delted

Comment: Is you `wp-content/uploads` currently under git? Why isn't it just ignored in the project's `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to delete the directory in question as part of your post-receive command:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE="../" git checkout -f; rm -rf ../wp-content/uploads
```